# jQuery On Event get object listener

Tags: jquery, events

I have this markup:

```
<div class="foo">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

If I want to attach click to all children I will do:

```
var foo = $('.foo').on('click', ".child", function(e, data){
   //get foo here?
})
```

When child is clicked how can I get foo here? Disregard the fact that I know here that foo is the parent of clicked child. (not sure closest would work but that would be using selectors again, is there a more direct method?)

Comment: If there is only one `class="foo"` in page then you can use `foo` inside handler function and it will be the only one that exists

Comment: `$(this).closest(".foo")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`Event.delegateTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) to refer to the "parent" element, being the Element on whom the event handler was attached (`".foo"` in your case):

```js
$('.foo').on('click', ".child", function(e, data){
   console.log(e.delegateTarget)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
   <div class="child">1</div>
   <div class="child">2</div>
   <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

To recap, say you **click on a `<span>`** which is in a `<li>` which is in a delegator `<ul>` element

```
<ul><li>Lorem <span>ut florem</span></li>
```

and having:

```js
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(evt) {
```

- evt.**delegateTarget** = `<ul>…`
- evt.**currentTarget** = `<li>…`
- evt.**target** = `<span>…`